# I want to create the browser-extensions tag. Is that OK?

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing

There are quite a lot of questions about browser extensions and add-ons. However, there's no tag dedicated to them.

I want to create and add the [browser-extensions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-extensions) tag to the relevant questions. However, since I don't have free edit privileges yet, this is going to put some load on the reviewers. And because of the edit, questions will be bumped to the front page.

Considering this, is it all right if I edit questions to add [browser-extensions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-extensions) (I will address other issues in the question, if existent)?

---

This is a sample of the questions I want to edit:

Picked from search: [extension is:question](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=newest&q=extension%20is:question) (sort by New, 50 results per page):

- [Are official browser add-ons really safe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38033/are-official-browser-add-ons-really-safe)
- [Signing a browser extension](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34412/signing-a-browser-extension)
- [What bad coding practices makes a browser extension vulnerable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34123/what-bad-coding-practices-makes-a-browser-extension-vulnerable)
- [Any tool for scanning vulnerabilities in browser extensions?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33834/any-tool-for-scanning-vulnerabilities-in-browser-extensions)
- [What should I look for when auditing a Firefox extension / plugin?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32428/what-should-i-look-for-when-auditing-a-browser-extension-plugin)
- [How securely use Firefox Add-on to prevent steal data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18133/how-securely-use-firefox-add-on-to-prevent-steal-data)
- [Is using "HTTPS everywhere" extension secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16445/is-using-https-everywhere-extension-secure) <sup>[ 1 ]</sup>
- [Find malware in browser extensions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/malware-in-browser-extensions)
- [How do I check the code of a Chrome extension to make sure it's not stealing my info?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10962/how-do-i-check-the-code-of-a-chrome-extension-to-make-sure-its-not-stealing-my)
- [Are Google Chrome Extensions vulnerable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8427/are-google-chrome-extensions-vulnerable)

Picked from search: [plugin is:question -extension](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=newest&q=plugin%20is:question%20-extension) (it's a common mistake to mix the terms "plugin" and "extension")

- [Why do Chrome extensions need access to 'all my data' and 'browsing activity'?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8550/why-do-chrome-plugins-need-access-to-all-my-data-and-browsing-activity)
- [Can a Firefox add-on or plug-in access the user's websites' saved passwords in decrypted mode?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/can-a-firefox-add-on-or-plug-in-access-the-users-websites-saved-passwords-in-d)

<sup>[ 1 ]</sup> Questions about specific browser extensions would also fall in the scope of [browser-extensions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-extensions).

I won't retag questions about Flash, Java, ... plug-ins, because a plug-in is generally not browser extension, and would only clutter the search results within the new tag.

Comment: This sounds good. Don't worry about the burden on reviewers, we'll suck it up. Clobbering the front page is more of a worry. How many questions do you think need this tag? Do you have a sample?

Comment: @Gilles I've found 12 questions in two searches (filtered from 261 questions). It'll be retagged in reverse "active" order to make sure that the "active" tab of the tag is accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag sounds good to me in principle.

12 questions is ok to do in one go.

I'm not sure we really need to make the distinction between plugins and extensions (it's a bit of an implementation detail), but many of these questions aren't tagged [plugin](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) anyway and it's easier to merge tags than split them.

I say go for it. (Please wait a little to see if there are counter-arguments though.)